# Why does the output of Pandas DataFrame.sort_values differ from Series.sort_values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

While teaching, one of my students pointed out that Pandas `DataFrame.sort_values` returns a different ordering (different tie breaks) to that from the equivalent `Series.sort_values`.  Consider this

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/matthew-brett/806a356bb7b7
... 1f08c5c6d0c5235e2f3d/raw/facb1aab243a33033b46657378f65dcd41542596/business.csv'
... )
>>> df['name'].value_counts().head(6)
name
Peet's Coffee & Tea    20
Starbucks Coffee       13
McDonald's             10
Jamba Juice            10
STARBUCKS               9
Proper Food             9
Name: count, dtype: int64
>>> df.value_counts('name').head(6)
name
Peet's Coffee & Tea    20
Starbucks Coffee       13
McDonald's             10
Jamba Juice            10
Proper Food             9
STARBUCKS               9
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Of course, both of these orders are valid, given a not-stable default (quicksort) sort, but it's difficult to see why these would differ in the two cases, given the default method appears to be the same in both cases.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. unstable means unstable, which means same input can give different output in terms of original orders, for example, when you choose different pivot in quicksort.

Comment: @QuangHoang - did I not do enough in my question to show that I knew that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's different because the strategy is different for both methods.

To compute the `value_counts` of a `DataFrame`, Pandas use a [`groupby_size`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e86ed377639948c64c429059127bcf5b359ab6be/pandas/core/frame.py#L7267) but the default behavior of `groupby` is to sort keys in a lexicographic order by default.

`Series` compute `value_counts` in a more direct way.
`Series` use `IndexOpsMixin.value_counts` which use [`pandas.core.algorithms.value_counts_internal`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0c23e18c730ed8f35ae8d254455be84568b81578/pandas/core/base.py#L1010)

So to get the same result than a `Series`, use:

```
>>> df.groupby('name', sort=False).size().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)
name
Peet's Coffee & Tea          20
Starbucks Coffee             13
McDonald's                   10
Jamba Juice                  10
STARBUCKS                     9
Proper Food                   9
Mixt Greens/Mixt              8
Specialty's Cafe & Bakery     8
Philz Coffee                  7
The Organic Coup              7
dtype: int64

>>> df['name'].value_counts().head(10)
name
Peet's Coffee & Tea          20
Starbucks Coffee             13
McDonald's                   10
Jamba Juice                  10
STARBUCKS                     9
Proper Food                   9
Mixt Greens/Mixt              8
Specialty's Cafe & Bakery     8
Philz Coffee                  7
The Organic Coup              7
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Nice detective work ;)